# Как в Ruby-gems изменить переменную GEM_PATH под debian?

Tags: gems, ruby, debian

В мануалах написано, что в домашней папке находится файл .gemrc и из него при каждом запуске считываются переменные среды типа GEM_PATH и GEM_HOME, но у меня такого файла нет и при ручном его создании путь всё равно не меняется. Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: И главное непонятно, откуда он вообще берёт неправильный путь, если он нигде не указан.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум следует попробовать загнать в `.bashrc`.

**UPD**:
У каждой версии ruby свой gem. Видимо 1.9.1 поставился неправильно. `gem environment` выдаст информацию о связанной версии ruby.

Способ решения проблемы: удалить поставленный пакетом, и скачать с ruby-lang.org, и собрать самому. После этого поставить `rvm` (если есть необходимость в старой версии ruby).

Comment: Подробнее: версия ruby 1.9.1 (соответственно нужные gems в одноимённой папке), а gem environment видит только папку /var/lib/gems/1.8. Добавил переменную в .bashrc, не помогло.

Comment: Как ставили 1.9.1?

Comment: Как-как, через apt-get, конечно же. Только что обратил внимание на то, что gem эту версию вообще не видит. Видит 1.8.

Comment: gemы разные для разных рубей. Лучше снести и поставить заново. upd

Answer (score 0):

Помимо того, что у вас видятся неправильные версии gem'ов, так у вас ещё и все бинарники будут от 1.8. Можно, конечно, насоздавать симлинков для irb19, ruby19 и т.п., но проще воспользоваться [RVM](http://rvm.io) или [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/). Если не нравятся по каким-то причинам эти инструменты, или не нужны несколько разных версий Ruby одновременно, то можно воспользоваться скриптом [OhMyGems](http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2012/09/ohmygems.html).